# Unable to install titanium app on iPad device

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, titanium

I have developed an iPad application, It runs fine in simulator but when I try to install it on device, it gets installed to iTunes but syncing to iPad fails, prompting "Unable to intsall application".
Here are the Titanium environment details:

**Application type**: mobile

**Titanium SDK**: 1.8.3 (04/18/12 10:48 6c2fca1)

**Platform & version**: iOS 5.0

**Device**: physical iPad device (with iOS 5.1 (9B176))

**Host Operating System**: OSX 10.6.8

**Titanium Studio**: 2.0.1

I still unable to debug this issue as there are no logs/errors are shown, It just does not get installed.
Any help is highly appreciated.

=========================[Update]

When I try to install it via XCode, this is what I get in organiser console `Segmentation fault: 11`

```
May 24 03:44:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[2021] Builtin profile: gputoolsd (sandbox)
May 24 03:44:44 unknown ReportCrash[2027] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process installd[2025]
May 24 03:44:44 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[2026] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
May 24 03:44:44 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May 24 03:44:44 unknown ReportCrash[2027] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/xxxx using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Comment: this probably has nothing to do with the app. Is the iOS version suitable, is there enough space left on the iPad. Things like that ;)

Comment: Thanks for response. But I have checked points mentioned here. I have enough free space. But my iOS version is 5.1 in iPad. Could you elaborate more.

Comment: Do you have the certificate installed on your device? Is it for developer use? (activate that through xCode). Not sure if this is needed.

Comment: I don't see in any way how this can be an App issue

Comment: @Topener How do I install certificate on iPad?

Comment: I do see a warning on xCode as follows:

The version of iOS on “iPad01” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

Comment: apparently you use something which requires a higher version of iOS. So please do update.

Comment: @Topener: Hey, when I try to build same project from XCode, build succeed but after it prompts

    "There was an internal API error."